# Modify a field using the values of the other fields in the document

Tags: mongodb

### Initial Data

```js
db.members.insertMany([
   { "_id" : 1, "member" : "abc123", "status" : "A", "points" : 2, "misc1" : "note to self: confirm status", "misc2" : "Need to activate", "lastUpdate" : ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00Z") },
   { "_id" : 2, "member" : "xyz123", "status" : "A", "points" : 60, "misc1" : "reminder: ping me at 100pts", "misc2" : "Some random comment", "lastUpdate" : ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
])
```

### Update query

```js
db.members.update(
   { },
   [
      { $set: { status: "Modified", comments: [ "$misc1", "$misc2" ], lastUpdate: "$$NOW" } },
      { $unset: [ "misc1", "misc2" ] }
   ],
   { multi: true }
)
```

The above queries worked fine, I would like to know why we are passing the array instead of the object in the second parameter of `.update()`?

Why we can not do this with plain objects?

Comment: where did you found that query? and how you prepared this query?

Comment: its [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), because you are using internal fields value in another internal field `comments: [ "$misc1", "$misc2" ]` and also `lastUpdate: "$$NOW"`.

Comment: I found these query from MongoDB official docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because starting MongoDB 4.2 `update` commands support few Aggregation Pipelines in its update parameters.

You can learn more about this feature and pipelines supported at [this link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).

To summarise, If you are using a regular update, `Object` will be used. If you are
using Aggregation commands, `Array` will be used since you are passing pipelines
in the update parameter.

Legacy MongoDB update command does not have the option to self-reference other keys.
But it is possible in the `$set` pipeline stage of the MongoDB Aggregation.
That is why in the update query which you have used, `$set` Aggregation Pipeline is used
which supports referencing of other keys using `$`.

> Note: The use of Aggregation Pipelines in MongoDB update parameter is supported on MongoDB version > 4.2